# CodeIgniter force_download function does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, force-download

In the following code example, i am calling the download page. However, force_download does not work. There is no redirection, it stays on the same page because of i called the page as `index.php/sample/download`. Only the url is changing. But the download is not triggered. Also i can not call the page as direct `/sample/download`. Although i specify the required configuration for index.php (index_page), if i do not specify the download link as `/sample/index.php/sample/download`, it returns 404 error.

**application/controller/Sample.php**

```
class Sample extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url_helper', 'download'));           
        $this->load->model('Sample_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->getData();
        $this->load->view('sample/view', $data);
    }

    public function download() {
        $data = 'Here is some text!';
        $name = 'mytext.txt';
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
}
```

**application/views/sample/view.php**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/sample/download">Download file</a>
```

**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller']    = 'Sample';
$route['404_override']          = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes']  = FALSE;
$route['sample']                = 'sample/index';
$route['sample/download']       = 'sample/download';
```

Comment: routes not working or `force_download`?

Comment: May be try `$name =  FCPATH .'downloads/mytext.txt';`  create a folder in main directory called downloads make sure folder permission 0777 or may be place `exit()` under force_download()

Answer (score 0):

update your codes by following,

**application/controller/Sample.php**

```
class Sample extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url_helper', 'download'));           
        $this->load->model('Sample_model');
    }

    public function index() {
        //$data = $this->getData();                 // NOT DEFINED
        $this->load->view('sample/view', $data);
    }

    public function download() {
        $data = 'Here is some text!';
        $name = 'mytext.txt';
        force_download($name, $data);
    }
}
```

**application/views/sample/view.php**

```
<a href="<?= base_url('sample/download'); ?>">Download file</a>
```

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller']    = 'sample';
$route['404_override']          = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes']  = FALSE;
$route['sample']                = 'sample/index';
$route['sample/download']       = 'sample/download';
```

make sure your `.htaccess` file like same below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```